# Magento separate footer links

Tags: magento

Ok so I’m having so much trouble understanding all this block stuff. No matter how many times I re-read an article, I just can’t grasp it.

I have About Us, Customer Service, and Privacy Policy in the footer_links static block. Which I want in one section. 
Then I want the Site Map, Search Terms, Advanced Search, Orders and Returns, and Contact Us somewhere else.. I see that Magento mends both those footer link sections together in one block. Which I want them in two separate blocks.

How do I go about doing that??

I think I know how to add another block for the third set of links I want, but I’m having trouble trying to separate these two.

Answer (score 2):

Ah for anyone wanting to separate them, you put this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?>
```

The first one is for the default links defined by the footer_links block and then cms_footer_links is your cms static blocks that is called footer_links.. so you can define more blocks and use cms_whatever_you_call_it =)

And add this in your local.xml:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
                <!--
                    The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                    You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                -->
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
            </block>
```

Of course with the name="cms_whatever_you_call_it" :P

Comment: The number of ways to include a link set (or any content) like this in magento approaches infinity. Calling a static block directly, is probably better than going through getChildHtml (which is likely exactly what its doing).